# Python: Deleting lines from a file with certain criteria

Tags: python

I'm trying to delete lines from a file with certain criteria but when I run the script it just deletes the whole file. When I change the script to just 'read' the lines it returns the lines with the search criteria but when I open the file in 'write' mode it and change it from printing each line to remove each line it empties the whole thing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

f = raw_input('Enter filename > ')

with open(f, 'w+') as fobj:
    criteria = raw_input('Enter criteria > ')
    for eachLine in fobj:
        if criteria in eachLine:
            fobj.remove(eachLine)
            break


fobj.close()
```

Comment: Side note: you don't need `fobj.close()` if you're using a `with`-statement. Those handle closing behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you wanted to remove the line having particular criteria. You can simply create another file with and write the content in that file as following:

```
output = []
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    criteria = 'test'
    output =[line for line in lines if criteria not in line]


fin = open('newfile.txt', 'wb')
fin.writelines(output)
```

Comment: Cool. I figured I could do that but I was just confused why I couldn't get it to work with a file. I could do the same with just about any other iterable but not this file

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

```
w+ Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does not
   exist, otherwise it is truncated.  The stream is positioned at
   the beginning of the file.
a+ Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does not
   exist.  The stream is positioned at the end of the file.  Subse-
   quent writes to the file will always end up at the then current
   end of file, irrespective of any intervening fseek(3) or similar.
```

so you are truncating the file on the line containing the `with open`. You probably want to create a new file with a different name and rename it at the end of your program.